# Why is FieldInfo.GetValue(null) not working in static constructor

Tags: c#, reflection, static-constructor

See the code below. I want a class that automatically enumerates all the defined static readonly instances of its own type (see TestClass as an example, it defines 3 static readonly instances of its own type).

I want this automation because I want to loop over the defined types and not risk the change of forgetting to add a new instance to the list of `All`.

Ok, I have it working, that is not the point. But why doesn't `FillAll` work when called from a static constructor? See the commented static constructor in `DefinedInstancesBase<T>` code. I mean `FieldInfo.GetValue(null)` returns null in the static constructor, though the debugger has already hit creating the static readonly instances before the `FieldInfo.GetValue(null)` is called.

I'm very curious why it doesn't work. Is this by design?

```
public abstract class DefinedInstancesBase<T>
{
    public static IList<T> All
    {
        get
        {
            if (_All == null)
            {
                FillAll();
            }
            return _All;
        }
    }

    //Why this doesn't work? No idea.
    //static DefinedInstancesBase()
    //{
    //    FillAll();
    //}

    private static void FillAll()
    {
        var typeOfT = typeof(T);
        var fields = typeOfT.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        var fieldsOfTypeT = fields.Where(f => f.FieldType == typeOfT);
        _All = new List<T>();
        foreach (var fieldOfTypeT in fieldsOfTypeT)
        {
            _All.Add((T)fieldOfTypeT.GetValue(null));
        }
    }

    private static List<T> _All = null;
}

[TestClass]
public class DefinedInstancesTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void StaticReadOnlyInstancesAreEnumerated()
    {
        //Given
        var expectedClasses = new List<TestClass>
        {
            TestClass.First,
            TestClass.Second,
            TestClass.Third,
        };

        //When
        var actualClasses = TestClass.All;

        //Then
        for (var i=0; i<expectedClasses.Count; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedClasses[i].Id, actualClasses[i].Id);
        }
    }

    private class TestClass : DefinedInstancesBase<TestClass>
    {
        public static readonly TestClass First = new TestClass(1);
        public static readonly TestClass Second = new TestClass(2);
        public static readonly TestClass Third = new TestClass(3);

        public int Id { get; private set; }

        private TestClass(int pId)
        {
            Id = pId;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate issues at work here.

1. There is a typo in your `static` constructor in the code above. Try changing `static DefinedInstances()` to `static DefinedInstancesBase()`, because currently it is just specified as a private static function.
2. The second and more important issue is to understand the order that the various constructors are being called in. What is happening is that the static constructor on the base abstract class is getting triggered by the instantiation (during member initializer) of the `First` field in the derived class. Therefore, `First` is still null when the `static` constructor of `DefinedInstancesBase` class is being called (and thus the `FindAll()` method).

See the following code (slightly modified to better illustrate the issue) and  output:

```
public void Main()
{
    DefinedInstancesTest dit = new DefinedInstancesTest();
    dit.StaticReadOnlyInstancesAreEnumerated();
}

public abstract class DefinedInstancesBase<T>
{
    public static IList<T> All
    {
        get
        {
            //if (_All == null)
            //    FillAll();
            return _All;
        }
    }

    // correctly named static ctor
    static DefinedInstancesBase() { FillAll(); }

    private static void FillAll()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FillAll() called...");
        var typeOfT = typeof(T);
        var fields = typeOfT.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
        var fieldsOfTypeT = fields.Where(f => f.FieldType == typeOfT);
        _All = new List<T>();
        foreach (var fieldOfTypeT in fieldsOfTypeT)
        {
            _All.Add((T)fieldOfTypeT.GetValue(null));
        }
    }

    private static List<T> _All = null;
}

//[TestClass]
public class DefinedInstancesTest
{
    //[TestMethod]
    public void StaticReadOnlyInstancesAreEnumerated()
    {
        //Given
        var expectedClasses = new List<TestClass>
        {
            TestClass.First,
            TestClass.Second,
            TestClass.Third,
        };

        //When
        var actualClasses = TestClass.All;

        //Then
        for (var i=0; i<expectedClasses.Count; i++)
        {
            //Assert.AreEqual(expectedClasses[i].Id, actualClasses[i].Id);
            if (expectedClasses[i].Id != actualClasses[i].Id)
              Console.WriteLine("not equal!");
        }
    }

    private class TestClass : DefinedInstancesBase<TestClass>
    {
        public static readonly TestClass First;
        public static readonly TestClass Second;
        public static readonly TestClass Third;

        public int Id { get; private set; }

      static TestClass()
      {
        Console.WriteLine("TestClass() static ctor called...");
        First = new TestClass(1);
        Second = new TestClass(2);
        Third = new TestClass(3);
      }

        private TestClass(int pId)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("TestClass({0}) instance ctor called...", pId);
          Id = pId;
        }
    }
}

TestClass() static ctor called...
// the line "First = new TestClass(1);" now triggers the base class static ctor to be called,
// but the fields First, Second, and Third are all still equal to null at this point!
FillAll() called...
TestClass(1) instance ctor called...
TestClass(2) instance ctor called...
TestClass(3) instance ctor called...
// this null reference exception to be expected because the field value actually was null when FindAll() added it to the list
Unhandled Expecption: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: I do not follow.. It compiles. And `typeof(T)` is working. What do you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: Constructors have to have the same name as their class, yours does not. Your class is called DefinedInstancesBase, but the (commented out) constructor has a different name - it is called DefinedInstances, i.e., it is not actually a constructor.

Comment: Whoopsie, my bad. That was a renameI applied later on when the static constructor already became a piece of comment. So that is not the issue..

Comment: So essentially, try to make the `TestMethod` work by calling `FillAll()` in the `static constructor` instead of lazy loading the property `All`.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk It's not a lazy loading problem per se. It's that the static constructor in the base class is being called before the `First` field can be initialized to an object. So the current value of that field (at the time `FindAll()` is called) is correctly being returned as `null`.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Edited my answer to include full code and logging to illustrate the constructor ordering issue. The solution is to not call `FindAll()` in a constructor but call it manually instead, or lazy-load it in the property getter like you were originally doing.

Comment: Yes that is it! Silly me, I must have had pooh in my eyes and a pepper in my ass for not taking the time to figure this out myself! Thanks so must for demystification! :)

Comment: No worries; inheritance can definitely make things more complex.